# Android Gradle: flavors and Urban Airship

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, urbanairship.com, android-productflavors

I have a question:

I'm using the flavors feature that Gradle has, in order to use different icons, etc., but I have realized that, if I'm using them, then `Urban-Airship` doesn't work.

`nl.myapp.is.staging E/MyApp - UALib﹕ Required permission nl.myapp.is.staging.permission.C2D_MESSAGE is unknown to PackageManager.`

Is there any way to workaround this? Is it still possible to use `UA` while also using flavors in Android Studio?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You still need to configure either the main android manifest file for Urban Airship or the flavor specific manifest file. Use ${applicationId} if you are setting up UA for multiple packages.

Here is the full guide on setting up the manifest: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/android.html#modify-the-androidmanifest-xml